# How to detect rendered new lines in text node

Tags: javascript, jquery, detection

Heyy guys.

First of all, I'm not trying to detect a \n in a text node. What I need to know is when/where a text will wrap to the other line.

My idea was to iterate over the TextNode, letter by letter, create a new TextNode compound of all letters until the current step, after that I would calculate the height of the text node, if the height of the current step is different from the previous one, then the line wrapped.

The problem is I'm having a hard time to figure out the height of the current text. This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mfnAT/2/

You can see that the height returned by `getTextNodeHeight` is incorrect and I don't know what is wrong. I found this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961022/measure-bounding-box-of-text-node-in-javascript).

Any of you guys know how to solve this? Or a better approach for this problem?

Comment: Why did you get the text height ...??? You need to get text width only i think...

Comment: As I said "if the height of the current step is different from the previous one, then the line wrapped". Width? o.O

Comment: Are you trying to collect the position information when you detect a /n or call a function?

Comment: When I detect a new line I wanna insert something there.

Comment: Found what I wanted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671713/detecting-line-breaks-with-jquery =)

Answer (score 0):

Set a coordinate somewhere in the middle of your text. call the left offset relative to this position at a given time interval measured by setTimeout. Initialize one event listener on page load that listens for the left offset to be negative ( meaning it is now to the right of this position) That event listener simply Initializes a second event listener that listens for the left offset to be positive, which would symbolize a \n. Call the two event listeners back and forth. I will be back on in a few hours if you have questions.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand. Any examples? =)

Comment: Yeah I am not good with explaining, I will add in some code. I just wanted to know what happens when you get an /n occurance. just in general like run a function or what?