# Measure height of text node

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is any way you can measure height of text node **without wrapping it**?

I've tried useless native method `node.style.height`, then `node.clientHeight`, then jQuery method `$(node).height()`

It gives me javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined`

here is my playground: http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/F99mm/1/

Comment: You mean besides opening it in the developer tools and looking at the computed height?

Comment: yes, I need it in javascript for purpose... It's dynamically generated mixed content, and i need to know what it's enough :)

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/F99mm/2/

Comment: @ManofSnow The question says, "**without wrapping it**"

Comment: no i need to measure TEXT node, it's a simple text without any tag like <span> or <div>

Comment: yes, feel like a solution... thanks James.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before asking questions like this. Searching for your exact title returns the exact result you got below. You obviously didn't take 30 seconds to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try getting the **bounding box** of the TextNode (Using Range, will set **height** to height of **bounding box**):

```
var height = 0;
if (document.createRange) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
    if (range.getBoundingClientRect) {
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect) {
            height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        }
    }
}
```

and replace **textNode** with something like `document.body.firstChild;`.

Some of code taken from [Measure bounding box of text node in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961022/measure-bounding-box-of-text-node-in-javascript)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gdn6C/103/)**

Comment: I don't understand why this got a downvote, it works with non-textwrapped text nodes

Comment: This seems line a nice answer, I too don't understand the downvote so I will fix it

Comment: @XGreen Thanks, it looks like they un-downvoted :)

Comment: I could see a down-vote because you copied and pasted an answer from another question. This question should have been closed as a duplicate instead, quoting the answer you copied. I don't believe it adds value to Stack Overflow to copy/paste answers... really thought the OP should have searched Stack Overflow first, the answer is obvious with a quick search.

Comment: yep, working just fine... but really weird function :) tested http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/F99mm/5/

Comment: @Jasper You're right, I've just read and it said not to copy *complete* text.  However, I think that I changed it *enough...*

Comment: @ManofSnow The answer you copied perfectly answered this question. So there's no need to re-write anything, just vote to close the question as a duplicate of the original question. If you add some value to the answer by adding some additional information, that's got value but I don't see any extra information, just less.

Comment: @Jasper I just edited my answer and tried to make it more 'original'